# long page-loading time

Tags: language-agnostic

I've been working on [this website](http://www.iol.ie/~murtaghd/stef). [One of the pages](http://www.iol.ie/~murtaghd/stef/service.html) takes an extraordinarily long time to load (about 1 minute). I'm very puzzled by this, because the other pages load in a reasonable amount of time, and there's no obvious explanation for why this page should load slowly, e.g. no large images or computationally intensive JavaScript.

### Update

I removed the reference to the missing .js file - thanks for pointing this out. The page still takes a very long time to load, so it seems like this was not the only problem.

Comment: One of the requests on your page is timing out with the error: 504 Proxy Timeout ( The...see ISA Server Help. ).

Answer (score 1):

Run the particular page on [pagespeed online](http://pagespeed.googlelabs.com/) by Google.

Answer (score 1):

Something in your page cannot be found and this is causing a redirect to http://home.iol.ie/common/error/notfound.asp

The problem seems to be that notfound.asp is throwing a Network Access Message.

It seems that the item that isn't being found is:

> ./js/foo.js

Even so, the bigger problem is that your error page is having a problem itself.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there's something missing on your page.

> [20:50:02.111] GET
>   http://home.iol.ie/common/error/notfound.asp
>   [undefined 20982ms]

This page is looking for something and taking a long time before it gives up. Are you sure everything on the page is accounted for?

Comment: Do you mean a missing image, .css or .js file?

Comment: I don't think it's the missing item that's causing the problem. There IS a missing item, but the error page itself is what's causing the load time.

Answer (score 0):

I clicked on 'View Source'. All the javascript files can be viewed instantly except "./js/foo.js". This is causing the page to hang. Does this file exist or could it be inaccessible?